# Building an array of non-sequential variables

Tags: arrays, sas

I have a dataset with ~6000 variables, which are in 82 groups. The variable names are all in the form "a001yr, a001sta, a001tot... a082tot" (in other words, "*a***cyclenum***setsuffix*"). Is there a way to cleanly pick out all the numeric variations of one particular set, (e.g. a001yr, a002yr, ... a082yr) to build an array? Or am I stuck writing out the full set of variables by hand?

(I'm using SAS 9.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description is still kinda of vague, what rules to define 'one particular set'? For your example, you could try the following:

```
 proc sql;
  select name into :varname separated by ' ' from dictionary.columns 
where libNAME='WORK' and upcase(memname)='TEST' AND PRXMATCH('/a\d+yr/io',name) > 0 and type='num';
quit;
```

The code uses PRX functions (which I believe they are available for 9.2) to pick out those variable names from 'WORK' library, 'TEST' table, that are start with 'a', then bunch of numbers, and end with 'yr' and also numeric, then put them into a macro variable varname, so you can use it in your downstream data step code, such as:

```
data want;
 set test;
 array tst &varname;
 blah blah;
 run;
```

Comment: The proc sql statement is returning "No rows were selected", even when I pare it down to just the libname= and memname= conditions.

And, yes, I did change the libname and memname to the appropriate library and table for my code.

Comment: libname has to be all caps.

Comment: Ah, got it. I'm not terribly familiar with PERL regular expressions; what's the purpose of the 'io' at the end of the expression?

Comment: 'i' to Ignore cases, so AB=ab; 'o' to compile only Once, to boost efficiency.